# Visual Studio 2017 - Css Editor - Component Error

Tags: visual-studio

При открытии CSS файлов в студии вылетает ошибка компонента и редактор сбивает разметку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файле лога ActivityLog.xml содержится следующая информация.

```
  <entry>
    <record>746</record>
    <time>2017/11/17 18:49:57.319</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>
        System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
        Parameter name: value
        at System.Enum.ToObject(Type enumType, Object value)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.DialogPage.SetPropertyValue(PropertyDescriptor descriptor, Object automationObject, Object value)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.DialogPage.LoadSettingFromStorage(PropertyDescriptor prop)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.DialogPage.LoadSettingsFromStorage()
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.DialogPage.set_Site(ISite value)
        at System.ComponentModel.Container.Add(IComponent component, String name)
        at System.ComponentModel.Container.Add(IComponent component)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetDialogPage(Type dialogPageType)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.Package.CSS.CssPackage.GetAutomationObject(String name)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.GetAutomationObject(String propName, Object&amp; auto)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Editor.Package.Settings.Common.WebSettingsStorageWithDialog.LoadFromStorage()
        at Microsoft.Web.Editor.Host.WebEditor.GetSettings(String contentTypeName)
        at Microsoft.CSS.Editor.Settings.CssSettings.get_Storage()         
        at Microsoft.CSS.Editor.Settings.CssSettings.get_ValidationEnabled()
        at Microsoft.CSS.Editor.Checker.CssErrorTagger..ctor(ITextBuffer textBuffer)
        at Microsoft.CSS.Editor.Checker.CssErrorTagger.Attach(ITextBuffer textBuffer)
        at Microsoft.CSS.Editor.Checker.CssErrorTaggerProvider.CreateTagger[T](ITextBuffer textBuffer)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.GatherTaggers(ITextBuffer textBuffer)
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
    </description>
  </entry>
```

Ну и страница редактора показывает ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал отключать и подключать компоненты для работы с ASP.NET включающий CSS компоненты, но что-то ничего не вышло. Попробовал вызвать восстановление, опять же ничего. Есть идеи, как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня такая же проблема, но возникает в VS2015, после того как я поменял настройки для Text Editor/CSS/Advanced в VS2017.

Исправил так: запустить regedit, найти ветку HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ApplicationPrivateSettings\TextEditor\CSS и удалить в ней секцию Specific.

Надеюсь поможет.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with loading CSS files. The problem I had was, that my Visual Studio was synced with settings from the cloud. I had an extension previously installed, and this setting was synced to cloud. When I hadn't the extension any longer, VS still tried to sync the setting and failed.

I always got an error on opening CSS files and I wasn't able to open the Tools-Options-Text Editor-CSS-Advanced dialog.

For me, following helped:

1. Signed out from Visual Studio and closed all instances
2. Calling devenv /resetuserdata
3. Calling devenv /resetsettings
4. Not sure if needed, but then I deleted "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio" folder (will be recreated on next start again)
5. Start Visual Studio and disable syncing of settings "Tools-Options-Environment-Accounts" and Untick "Synchronize settings"
6. After that, you can re-login to your VS account and everything should be fine.

Hope that helps you too.

Comment: Our working language is Russian, therefore please translate your answer into russian.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it didn't solve my problem. I also have a same problem in visual studio 2015 and I don't know what wrong with it. However VS2015 doesn't ruin the code style as VS2017 and I can continue coding after an error.